# How to retrieve a route pattern from a route name in a Symfony Controller

Tags: php, symfony, controller, routes, twig

I would like to basically get the same result as Twig's function **path(routeName)** but not in the **view.html.twig** but inside a controller itself.

*routing.yml* :

```
MyBundle_route_first:
pattern:  /dummy/first/{foo}
defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Dummy:First }
requirements:
  _method:  GET
  foo: \d+

MyBundle_route_second:
pattern:  /dummy/second/{foo}/{bar}
defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Dummy:Second }
requirements:
  _method:  GET
  foo: \d+
  bar: \d+
```

*controller.php* :

```
class DummyController extends Controller {

  public function firstAction($foo) {
    // do some stuff
  }
  public function secondAction($foo, $bar) {
    // do some stuff
  }

  public function anotherAction() {
    $firstRoutePattern = some_magic_function("MyBundle_route_first");
    // "/dummy/first/{foo}"

    $secondRoutePattern = some_magic_function("MyBundle_route_second");
    // "/dummy/second/{foo}/{bar}"

  }
}
```

Any help or link to a related topic would be much apreciated.

Have a good day :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this method : [generate](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.html#method_generate)

```
$firstRoutePattern = $this->container->get('router')->generate('MyBundle_route_first', array('foo' => $foo));
```

Comment: Actually, the right syntax including the parameter to pass to the **generate** function was:
`$firstRoutePattern = $this->container->get('router')->generate('MyBundle_route_first', array('foo' => $foo));`

But you put me in the right direction ;-)

Comment: And since you are in a controller you might try: $this->generateUrl('MyBundle_route_first', array('foo' => $foo));  Lots of useful helper functions in the base controller class.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad, I'll check it out. I'm still learning this huge framework !

Comment: Controller shortcut are nice but I think it's important to know the original method as it can be useful for service definition.